# How to get the chapter name in a single page without effecting the Bibliography heading?

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, natbib

so I wanted to put the chapter title in a single page, I used this code

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\vspace*{\fill}
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule\Huge}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]
```

plus the {titlesec} package, but this effected my bibliography title as well it's now like this
[image]

I want it to be like it used to be in the same page as the references

[image]

I tried creating a custom chapter like this:

```
\newcommand*\mychapter[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@chapapp{Chapitre}
    \def\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \chapter{#2}
    \else
    \chapter[#1]{#2}
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
```

then applying the same method on this but instead of writing \chapter I wrote \mychapter but nothing happened it didn't change, I am using natbib and unsrtnat style (I don't think it's important though)

so is there anyway to put the chapter title in a single page without effecting the Bibliography?

Comment: Do you also want your bibliography with a rule above (and, of course, no number)?

Comment: by default it's like the second picture and yea i would like it like the second picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, try adding the formatting with the `numberless` key (all unnumbered chapters will be formatted the same way), and adjust to your needs:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{}
{0pc}
{\Huge}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer it fixed the problem but I still have the line on top of the bibliography heading, is there a way to remove it? (sorry I am still new to this, I have just searched but couldn't find a good way)

Comment: Just, remove `\titlerule` from the code and use preferably the `block` style. Sorry, I had misunderstood what you wanted exactly.

Comment: it's okay, thank you! it's all good now!

Comment: Glad to have been helpful!